# Javascript Date() returns wrong date

Tags: javascript, date

I've been looking for someone with the same problem here but I could not find. Whenever I call Date() on my hidden value it seems to be subtracting one day. I am using Chrome.

I am passing a hidden value to my html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="start_date" value="2018-07-29" class="start-date" id="id_start_date">
```

It's correct when I call:

```
var hiddenDate =  $('#id_start_date')[0].value;
alert(hiddenDate);   # 2018-07-29
```

But incorrect if I call:

```
var date = new Date(hiddenDate);
alert(date); # Sat Jul 28 2018 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: timezones......

Comment: It was parsed as UTC (the time is 5 hours behind in your UTC-0500 timezone). The right way to deal with that depends on what you end up doing with the date object. So: where does `date` go?

Comment: I'd convert to timestamp instead of java's `Date` object.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Comment: @Ry-  I increment that value to set up days for an entire week. I've tried the suggested solutions in this post but had no success.

Comment: Try using the UTC equivalents of functions on the date object you already have, then, like `getUTCDate()` instead of `getDate()`. (Dates are really hard to get right, though.)